# Как скачать с гитхаб приватный репозиторий одной командой git

Tags: git

```
git clone [url] - Спрашивает логин и пароль.
```

Мне нужно либо скачать одной командой, либо сделать так чтобы bash скрипт давал юсернейм и пароль

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10054318/4827341

Comment: С генерируйте ssh ключ, и все у Вас получиться https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-SSH-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0